# Tell me what it would look like to factor $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ a different way

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring

During the factoring of $x^2-1$ I saw a $+x$ and $-x$ were introduced but I wonder how the factoring would go if the $+x-x$ were added in reverse, like so $-x+x$.

I was shown $x^2-1$ can be factored to $(x+1)(x-1)$ thusly...
$x^2-1 =$
$x^2+x-x-1 =$
$(x^2+x)-(x+1) =$
$(x*x+x*1)+(-1)*(x+1) =$
$x*(x+1)+(-1)*(x+1) =$
$(x+(-1))(x+1) =$
$(x-1)(x+1) =$

I want to know how $x^2-1$ can be factored to $(x+1)(x-1)$ if instead of $x^2+x-x-1 =$ the $+x$ and $-x$ were brought in the other way around like so $x^2-x+x-1 =$

I tried to factor this to $(x-1)(x+1)$ and got lost along the way.

I'll start the equation again.
$x^2-1 =$
$x^2-x+x-1 =$
... what happens next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you don't understand,
First of all, Addition is a commutative operation so, it won't matter how you "add"
You're lost at this point..?
$x^2-x+x-1$
Hint: Just Take the common factor out, like you did first, earlier you took $+1$ common. Something else this time. and obviously, $+x$ from the first two terms.

Just remember that the result would be the same, however you factor out.

If you still couldn't understand,
$$x^2-x+x-1$$
$$=(x)(x-1)+(+1)(x-1)$$
$$ (x-1)[(x)+(+1)]$$
$$\implies (x-1)(x+1)$$

Comment: "I don't understand what you don't understand" I'll add to the OP and show my work and how it doesn't get me to the same result.

Comment: It gets you to the same result , man (>ლ). By that, I meant I don't understand what you possibly couldn't understand in the simple equation where you have to take the common factor out.

Comment: I'm sure it gets the same result. I'm learning how to factor equations. I don't know the steps to get from $x^2-x+x-1$ to $(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Fine. I'll edit.

Comment: Ah. I see. I got up to the point where you put a bracket around the parenthesis. I didn't know you could do that. Thank you.

Comment: "I didn't know you could do that" the common factor here was $(x-1)$  itself.

Comment: I see. It just feels like the (+1) came out of nowhere and might make the equation wrong by +1. I know it was put on the right side to multiply by 1 and make no change, but now it is being added to the x on the left. I'm new to this, so it seems one could have not added a +1 to the equation and the equation could have been (x)(x-1), which I'm sure is wrong. The added -1 and +1 cancel each other out(?), but what if you multiplied a part by 1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1 would this mean you need to add a -8? I'm serious and not trolling here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108798/discussion-between-ashwhole-and-renoldus).

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2-x+x-1=x*x-x*1+(x-1)$$or

$$x(x-1)+(x-1)$$
Which gives you what you want